# make new file every time redirect operation is run

Tags: node.js, io-redirection

I'm starting my node application with:

```
node index.js > logfile.log 2> errorlog.log
```

The problem is that those files `logfile.log` and `errorlog.log` get created again every time you run the command. How can I create a file with a different name every time for example add a date to the filename or some other alternate solution ?

Comment: You can create a script that takes the current date and puts is in the name of the file. Also, you can just run this command `node index.js >> logfile.log 2>> errorlog.log` which is going to append new lines to existing files insted of creating new files.

Comment: Nice! I think using >> operator is the solution here, please post an answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for keeping this place welcoming and friendly!

Comment: You're welcome. My intent was not too be snide. The people helping you here here are volunteers, which is why the rule page [ask] emphasizes that wasting their time with poorly researched questions like this is disrespectful.

Comment: Don't let the fact that blazej is knowledgeable and kind distract you from the lack of research and consequent downvotes in your question. Also, please don't misconstrue my feedback as anything other than what it is. I'm not judging you, just wishing for some semblance of quality on a site I appreciate.

Comment: Understood, but it's really hard to google questions like these which are related to linux operators such as (<) because the google results for those are not so good. For you (i assume a person of experience) it might seem obvious but for beginners this is the only place where you can ask questions and learn. I am certain that my questions help other people as well. Nothing personal but this site already has a bad reputation.

Comment: @sander. The reputation comes from different problem solving approaches. I've found that professionals tend to think well of it while many beginners don't. I've also found that it's directly correlated to how much effort you're willing to put into solving the problem yourself first. Largely because the people that can help you are usually the professionals, not other noobs asking for teh codez. It's not elitism, it's just time management. And "it's hard to Google" is just another way to delegate it to someone else: i.e., implying that your time is more valuable.

Comment: You make good points. I've just noticed that when I've been asking "dumb" questions here they usually get quite a lot of views and upvotes and it's useful for other people. I see it as providing value for the community, even though I'm not dealing with the hardest problems on earth. For me personally, I learn better by talking to people vs reading documentation. But I get what you mean and I agree also with your points.

Comment: From my own experience I know that sometimes it is hard to google an answer for your question, especially either you don't really know what you're looking for or you don't know how to call it in a sensible way. I think that's the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is preety simple. You can just use `>>` insted of `>` which appends new lines to the file insted of creating a new one. Here is the command you should use:

```
node index.js >> logfile.log 2>> errorlog.log
```

Comment: Op wants a different file every time. Days so right in the question

Comment: @MadPhysicist OP asks about *some other alternate solution* as well. I suggested him in a comment this solution and he confirmed that this is helpful